# Exponent of a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite, matrix-exponential

Consider a positive semidefinite matrix $H$ and consider the matrix exponential

$$U = e^{-\beta H}.$$

Let the spectral decomposition of $H$ be

$$H = \sum_{k} \lambda_k u_k u_{k}^{*}. $$

Then, could I write $U$ in terms of $\lambda_k$ and $u_k$?

I think $U$ can be written as

$$U = \sum_{k} e^{-\beta \lambda_k} u_k u_k^{*}. $$

But, just by expanding $e^{-\beta H}$ in the form of a power series, I did not get the desired expression. There's also the question of what happens when some of the $\lambda_k$-s are $0$.

Comment: Before we try to answer your question , you should answer these 3 questions of mine, which are likely he same as those of other potential respondents. (i) Are we talking about a real or complex matrix or maybe a matrix over some other field? (ii) What is $\beta$? (iii) in the older literature, a positive semi-definite matrix was required to satisfy the condition of NOT being positive definite. Are you imposing this codition or not? i.e. What is your precise definition of "positive semi-definite"?

Comment: Doesn't this apply to Hermitian matrices in general?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding $\ e^{-\beta H}\ $ in power series *does* give the desired expression if you use the fact that $\ u_i^*u_j=\delta_{ij}\ $, from which it follows that if $\ \left(\sum_\limits k\lambda_ku_ku_k^*\right)^{n-1}=$$\,\sum_\limits{k}\lambda_k^{n-1}u_ku_k^* \ $ then
\begin{align}
H^n&=\left(\sum_k\lambda_ku_ku_k^*\right)^n\\
&=\sum_k\lambda_ku_ku_k^*\left(\sum_k\lambda_ku_ku_*\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_i\lambda_iu_iu_i^*\sum_k\lambda_k^{n-1}u_ku_k^*\\
&=\sum_i\sum_k\lambda_i \lambda_k^{n-1}u_iu_i^*u_ku_k^*\\
&=\sum_i\lambda_i^nu_iu_i^*\ ,
\end{align}
and hence that $\ H^n=\sum_\limits{k}\lambda_k^nu_ku_k^* \ $ by induction.

Answer (score 0):

You can define $f(U)$ for any function $f$ defined on $\{\lambda_i\}$ by
$$f(U)=\sum f(\lambda_i)u_iu_i^*$$ The operators $P_i=u_iu_i^*$ form a family of mutually orthogonal one dimensional projections, i.e. $P_iP_j=0$ if $i\neq j$ and $P_i^2=P_i.$ Thus we get
$$f(U)g(U)=(fg)(U)$$ Moreover if the function $f$ is a pointwise limit of the functions $f_n$ then
$$f(U)=\lim_nf_n(U)$$
The latter can be applied to the partial sums of the function $e^{-\beta x}.$

**Remark** In the infinite dimensional case we have to restrict to the functions continuous on the set $\{\lambda_i\}$ and the pointwise convergence should be replaced by the uniform one.